# Gensim Word2Vec Model trained but not saved

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am using gensim and executed the following code (simplified):

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(...)
mode.build_vocab(sentences)
model.train(...)
model.save('file_name')
```

After days my code finished `model.train(...)`. However, during saving, I experienced:

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I noticed that there were some npy files generated:

```
<...>.trainables.syn1neg.npy
<...>.trainables.vectors_lockf.npy
<...>.wv.vectors.npy
```

Are those intermediate results I can re-use or do I have to rerun the entire process?

Answer (score 4):

Those are parts of the saved model, but unless the master `file_name` file (a Python-pickled object) exists and is complete, they may be hard to re-use.

However, if your primary interest is the final word-vectors, those are in the `.wv.vectors.npy` file. If it appears to be full-length (same size at the `syn1neg` file), it may be complete. What you're missing is the dict that tells you which word is in which index.

So, the following *might* work:

1. Repeat the original process, with the *exact* same corpus & model parameters, but only through the `build_vocab()` step. At that point, the new `model.wv.vocab` dict should be identical as the one from the failed-save-run.
2. Save that model, without ever `train()`ing it, to a new filename.
3. Confirming that `newmodel.wv.vectors.npy` (with randomly-initialized untrained vectors) is the same size as `oldmodel.wv.vectors.npy`, copy the oldmodel file to the newmodel's name.
4. Re-load the new model, and run some sanity checks that the words make sense.
5. Perhaps, save off just the word-vectors, using something like `newmodel.wv.save()` or `newmodel.wvsave_word2vec_format()`.

Potentially, the resurrected `newmodel` could also be patched to use the old `syn1neg` file as well, if it appears complete. It *might* work to further train the patched model (either with or without having  reused the older syn1neg).

Separately: only the very largest corpuses, or an installation missing the gensim cython optimizations, or a machine without enough RAM (and thus swapping during training), would usually require a training session taking days. You might be able to run much faster. Check:

- Is any virtual-memory swapping happening during the entire training? If it is, it will be disastrous for training throughput, and you should use a machine with more RAM or be more aggressive about trimming the vocabulary/model size with a higher `min_count`. (Smaller `min_count` values mean a larger model, slower training, poor-quality vectors for words with just a few examples, and also counterintuitively worse-quality vectors for more-frequent words too, because of interference from the noisy rare words. It's usually better to ignore lowest-frequency words.)
- Is there any warning displayed about a "slow version" (pure Python with no effective multi-threading) being used? If so your training will be ~100X slower than if that problem is resolved. If the optimized code is available, maximum training throughput will likely be achieved with some `workers` value between 3 and 12 (but never larger than the number of machine CPU cores).
- For a very large corpus, the `sample` parameter can be made more aggressive – such as `1e-04` or `1e-05` instead of the default `1e-03` – and it may both speed training *and* improve vector quality, by avoiding lots of redundant overtraining of the most-frequent words.

Good luck!