# Gensim Doc2vec trained, but not saved

Tags: model, save, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

While I trained d2v on a large text corpus I received these 3 files:

```
doc2vec.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy

doc2vec.model.vocabulary.cum_table.npy

doc2vec.model.wv.vectors.npy
```

Bun final model has not saved, because there was not enough free space available on the disk.

```
OSError: 5516903000 requested and 4427726816 written
```

Is there a way to resave my model using these files in a shorter time, than all training time?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the model in RAM, in an environment (like a Jupyter notebook) where you can run new code, you could try to clear space (or attach a new volume) and then try a `.save()` again. That is, you don't need to re-train, just re-save what's already in RAM.

There's no routine for saving "just what isn't already saved". So even though the subfiles that *did* save could potentially be valuable if you were desperate to salvage anything from the 1st training run (perhaps via a process like in [my `Word2Vec` answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281241/gensim-word2vec-model-trained-but-not-saved), though it's a bit more complicated with `Doc2Vec`), trying another save to the same place/volume would require getting those existing files out-of-the-way. (Maybe you could transfer them to remote storage in case they'll be needed, but delete them locally to free space?)

If you try to save to a filename that ends ".gz", gensim will try to save everything compressed, which might help a little. (Unfortunately, the main vector arrays don't compress very well, so this might not be enough savings alone.)

There's no easy way to slim an already-trained model in memory, without potentially destroying some of its capabilities. (There are hard ways, but only if you're sure you can discard things a full model could do... and it's not yet clear you're in that situation.)

The major contributors to model size are the number of unique-words, and the number of unique doc-tags.

Specifying a larger `min_count` *before training* will discard more low-frequency words – and very-low-frequency words often just hurt the model anyway, so this trimming often improves three things simultaneously: faster training, smaller model, and higher-quality-results on downstream tasks.

If you're using plain-int doc-tags, the model will require vector space for all doc-tag ints from 0 to your highest number. So even if you trained just 2 documents, if they had plain-int doc-tags of `999998` and `999999`, it'd still need to allocate (and save) garbage vectors for 1 million tags, 0 to 999,999. So in some cases people's memory/disk usage is higher than expected because of that – and either using contiguous IDs starting from `0`, or switching to string-based doc-tags, reduces size a lot. (But, again, this has to be chosen before training.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have my model in RAM. About resaving model using that tutorial for word2vec, I'll try to do it, thank you, is there any major differences I should know?

Comment: There should be extra docvecs-specific files in the `Doc2Vec` case you'd have to account for. Of the 3 files you listed as having been saved, none are the file with trained doc-vectors, so if you need those, you'll have to re-train – there's no hope of recovering those from the 3 files you've mentioned.

Comment: You could maybe experiment with training a smaller test Doc2Vec model - save it, see all its files... including those analogous to the 3 you have. (If they're not visible, you'd have to try a larger model, bc subfiles are only used when the arrays are over a certain size.) Try deleting all but those 3, and see if you can reconstruct a usable model. If it works on the smaller test model, repeat on the larger.

Comment: But really, the only thing sure to work is re-training and making sure you have enough space for the results to be saved. And doing it in a notebook would give you a better chance of recovering from a mid-process error, because the interim results would still be in RAM, so you could (for example) clear disk space then try another `save()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they really helped me to stop wasting my time trying to recover this model. )) Very interesting tip about doing it in a notebook, I'll try it, thanks!